# In Aaronson's "The Learnability of Quantum States", what do $E_j$ and $E$ represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

In an interesting paper by [Scott Aaronson](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0608142), he demonstrate the learnability of quantum states in a framework of pac-learning in machine learning. Here what he wrote:

[image]

But I am wondering what is the role of $E$ and how it is different from any member of the set $\mathcal{E} = \{E_j\}_{j=1}^{m}$, because in the first inequality he is using the $E_j$ and in the second after the "it also satisfies..." he is using only $E$ with no indice.

- what is the difference between the measurements $E_j$ and the measurement $E$?
- elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are measurements or results of measurements?
- **IF** THE $E_j$s are measurements, what is $E$?

what am I missing?

Comment: Don't use screenshot/images for text passages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $E$ is just there to simplify the problem (if complicating the problem statement).  We normally think of a measurement as a Hermitian operator $O$ such that the $n$th moment of the probability distribution of the value that you will get when you measure a state $\rho$ is $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho O^n)$.   His goal is to formalize the idea of "learning the result of a measurement," so in order to learn the results of $O$ on $\rho$, we need to come up with some criterion by which we can say that we've learned the whole distribution of measurements sufficiently well, which means we have to mess with the moments and for the most part that's a distraction from the point that he's trying to make.  His scheme of two-outcome [POVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM), on the other hand, is the most general way to map states $\rho$ into a single probability $p(\rho) \in [0,1]$, and so "learning the state" is inverting this operation and estimating $\rho$ from a bunch of measurements $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho E_i)$.

- When he's discussing $E$ with no subscript, he's talking about a measurement in the abstract.  When he talks about $E_i$, he's specifically making reference to the idea of drawing a bunch of $E_i$s from the distribution $\mathcal{D}$ in the sense of the set $\mathcal{E} = \{E_i\}$ that's used in this theorem.
- This set $\mathcal{E}$ is a set of measurements (i.e. two-outcome POVMs), not real-number results or expectations of measurements; the expectation of the measurement $E_i$ is $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho E_i)$.
- The $E$ in the second equation is parameterized by the $\mathrm{Pr}_{E\in\mathcal{D}}$, which is the probability of the event in square brackets occuring when $E$ is sampled from the distribution $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: so, E with no subscript can be a measurement to be performed on the state and the elements $E_j$ foring the training set are measurements already performed? That was my interpretation, specially when he states the results in the first two inequalities: given that the measurements already performed, the training set, respects such inequality any future measurement will respect the Pr(...) probability inequality. Is it reasonable?

Comment: I don't think I would differentiate them by whether they're "really performed," because Aaronson isn't really specifying an experimental setup/protocol.  $E$ is the letter that he uses for arbitrary measurements, and because his theorem uses the notion of a fixed (but arbitrary) finite set of measurements, he writes that set as $\mathcal{E} = \{E_i\}$ and labels them individually by $E_i$ when it's helpful for him to pick out one in particular.

Comment: thanks for the comments